# Should the first be the last by composition of paths?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, groupoids

Given two paths $f,g:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow X$ with $f\left(1\right)=g\left(0\right)$
there is a composite $f.g$ defined by $t\mapsto f\left(2t\right)$
if $2t\leq1$ and $t\mapsto g\left(2t-1\right)$ otherwise.

> Would in not be better if this would define  $g.f$ instead of $f.g$?

Going out from $x=f\left(0\right)$, $f\left(1\right)=y=g\left(0\right)$
and $z=g\left(1\right)$, we have $f$ and $g$ as representatives
of arrows $\left[f\right]:x\rightarrow y$ and $\left[g\right]:y\rightarrow z$
in fundamental groupoid $\pi\left(X\right)$. This gives the composite
$\left[g\right]\left[f\right]:x\rightarrow z$.

In my view covariant
functors (here $\left[\right]:\mathbf{Top}\rightarrow\mathbf{Grpd}$)
are more natural than contravariant functors.

Comment: I would rather change the notation in Grpd.

Comment: @mercio Then you should do that in every category. Consistency is exactly what I am asking for. Maybe it would help if we would read from right to left, as in the Hebrew language.

Comment: Well, it's not unusual for category theorists to write $g\circ f$ as $fg$...

Comment: Who should win here: David or Goliath? I have much sympathy for David, put as a mathematician I choose for Goliath.

Comment: Philp Higgins book "Categories and Groupoids" downloadable from http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html consistently uses the "algebraists" convention that functions should be written on the right, as $(x)f$, and then we get a conmposite $fg$ as giving $(x)fg$, first $f$, then $g$. However we are not used to $(x)\sin$.  For groupoids and multiple groupoids, I find this convention much better, but have also used the other notation in the same book, writing $G \circ F$ for the composite of functors, first $F$, then $G$. It's a problem!

Comment: Many people find the notion of cohomology to be more "natural" than homology.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to choose composition from right to left in abstract categories, then indeed, it would be much more convenient to define the composition of paths from right to left again, i.e. $g.f$ in your question.