# why function argument is on right side $f(x)$ rather than on left side as $xf$

Tags: functions, soft-question, math-history, convention

Is there an advantage for writing function arguments on the right side as $f(x)$ rather than on the left side as $xf$? The latter looks more natural if we think about it in diagram as $domain \xrightarrow f codomain$, and it will make the function composition easier?

Comment: $x(f\circ g) = (xg)f$ looks a bit awkward.

Comment: Some people *do* use that notation (and they have differnt opinions about $f\circ g$ as well).

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, the point of the $xf$ notation would be to interpret $f\circ g$ as "first $f$, then $g$", so that $x(f\circ g)= (xf)g$

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/506762/75923 (for instance the comment of Ronnie Brown there).

Comment: There was sort of a push for this in the 60s, but I think it fizzled out.  Lawvere pushes for this convention, for instance, in "The elementary theory of the category of sets".

Answer (score 1):

Putting the operator to the right is indeed how it is done in [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). I once saw a claim in Abraham Robinson's book that the origin of the $f(x)$ notation derives from Newton. Certainly this would have to originate from late 16th or early 17th centuries.

Note: thanks to @Michael Hoppe for pointing out that the notation $f(x)$ is due to Euler in 1734.

Comment: $x\,\sin$ is  sort of RPN, which I appreciate on my trusty HP50.  However, it was Leibniz -- the grand wizard of notation -- who invents that notation. And as Voltaire put it:  «Le mieux est l'ennemi du bien.» Since a quarter of a millennium  no enemy was encountered.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, thanks for your comment. Do you have a reference for attributing the $f(x)$ notation to Leibniz? I am a big fan of the latter and would be happy to be able to attribute this to him, as well.

Comment: Well ... no.  I thought is was due to Leibniz, but it seems to be Leonard Euler who introduced $f(x)$ in 1734. I've searched http://eulerarchive.maa.org/date-write.html for a reference, but didn't succeed yet. Anyway, I thank you for correcting my knowledge concerning  the inventor of $f(x)$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: that's what I thought. Leibniz did not work with functions so much, though he is considered the one to have introduced the concept in his 1684 paper. He didn't work with derivatives either for the most part, but rather with $dx$ and $dy$.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the function *s* placed to the right of the variable even in modern notation, as in $n!$.

Comment: the derivative $f'$ too